# Definitional vs propositional equality in Coq lemma statements

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

When writing highly automated proofs in Coq (CPDT-style) proofs, building on extensive use of `eauto N`, I must often modify my lemma statements to allow `eauto` to use them easily. In particular, I must replace statements of form (1) `forall vars, P (f args)...` (where `P` appears in the thesis or among hypotheses) with form (2) `forall x args, x = f args -> P x -> ...`. With form (2), `eauto` can instantiate `x` as needed to the appropriate expression `e` (found via unification), and prove `e = f args` separately via its usual proof search. Instead, with form (1) it’s necessary to *rewrite* with `e = f args` during the proof, something that IIUC `eauto` doesn’t do (unless with dedicated `Hint Extern`).

Is there a better existing strategy for achieving the same result, in this style, possibly an automated one? The closest thing I’ve seen is the `applys_eq` tactic in Software Foundations’ LibTactics, which allows applying a lemma in form (1) yet get `e = f args` as a separate goal; however, that tactic requires a completely manual specification.

I understand what I ask might be too hard or slow; knowing this is a reasonable approach would be helpful to stop looking and go on. I’ve heard at least one experienced Coq user describe this same problem and the same approach.